# Global variables and multiprocessing

Tags: python, global-variables, multiprocessing

Please help me, I'm beginner in Python. In the following example, the varieble `process_pool` must be global it doesn't seem to be persistent --- each time(0.5 sec) `start_actions` is called, `process_pool` has a length of `1`. Why might this be?
I want to add new process to `process_pool` for control from main process.
How I can update process_pool in other process?

```
process_pool = []
def do_test(sensor_id, value):
    sleep(5)    

def start_actions(sensor_id, value):
     # create new Process, so as we have many call from web
     worker = mp.Process(target=do_test, name="do_test", args=(sensor_id, value))
     #add to pool for kill from main by signal
     process_pool.append((worker, datetime.now()))
     print "len(process_pool)=", len(process_pool) #Always 1
     worker.start()

def start_http():
     try:
         server = HTTPServer(("", 80), iHTTPServer)
         write_debug_log("Started http server...")
         server.serve_forever()        

class iHTTPServer(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):    
     def do_GET(self):
        #call function
        sensor_id=1
        value = 1
        start_actions(sensor_id, value) 

if __name__ == "__main__":
      http_worker = mp.Process(target=start_http, name="http_worker")
      http_worker.start()
      #start in Process for kill by signal
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help clarifying this question.

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes

Comment: It's not so simple in my case

Comment: server.serve_forever() is blicking call. And I can't use shared memory